# Копирование из текста файла в другой файл python

Tags: python

У меня есть папка с текстовыми файлами, мне нужно что-бы python скопировал 2-ую строчку каждого файла и ввёл её в итоговый текстовый файл. Кто может помочь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подправьте по свои нужды :)

```
# Модуль для работы с файловой системой
import os

# Получение текущей директории
start_dir = os.getcwd()
# Получение списка файлов в текущей директории
files = os.listdir(start_dir)
# Фильтрование по расширению текстовых файлов
txt = filter(lambda f: f.endswith(".txt"), files)

# Новый файл (со вторыми строчками)
new_file = open("new_file.txt", "w")

# Прохож по списку из текстовых файлов, лежащих в текущей директории
for t in txt:
    # Открытие очередного файла в режиме чтения
    old_file = open(t, "r")
    # Чтение первой строки (пропуск, так как никуда не записываем)
    old_file.readline()
    # Запись второй строки
    new_file.write(old_file.readline())
    # Безопасное закрытие очередного файла
    old_file.close()

# Безопасное закрытие нового файла (со вторыми строчками)
new_file.close()
```

Comment: Изменить нужно только текущую директорию, либо бросить скрипт в саму папку с файлами